# Calculate Date Columns in Datframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

[image]

I try to calculate these columns. I need two new columns,

- one named "Starttime" = Date + Time
- one named "Endtime" = Date + Time + Timedelta

I need them for a gantt diagram in python, the problem ist, that time could appear multiple times. Any Idea how to solve this?

I red them out from a Dataframe and got this error here

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.time'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `pd.to_datetime` and `pd.to_timedelta`:

```
df['Starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].map(str) + ' ' + df['Time'].map(str))
df['Endtime'] = df['Starttime'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['TimeDelta'])
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert `date`s and `time`s to strings by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) and then use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), for second column use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.to_datetime(['06.12.2019','06.12.2019']).date,
                   'Time': pd.to_datetime(['17:20:10','17:20:31']).time,
                   'TimeDelta':['00:00:21','14:31:09']})

df['Starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['Time'].astype(str))
df['Endtime'] = df['Starttime'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['TimeDelta'])
print (df)
         Date      Time TimeDelta           Starttime             Endtime
0  2019-06-12  17:20:10  00:00:21 2019-06-12 17:20:10 2019-06-12 17:20:31
1  2019-06-12  17:20:31  14:31:09 2019-06-12 17:20:31 2019-06-13 07:51:40
```